# Call Swift overloaded operator from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, operator-overloading

Is it possible to call a custom operator, overloaded in Swift, from Objective-C?

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not as an operator.  You would have to wrap in a more normal function inside of a class.